# Cannot mint ERC223 token

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Hello I have a simple implementation for a ERC223 Token. I use this repository: [ERC223-token-standard](https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard)

Here is my contract Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

import "./ERC223-token-standard-development/token/ERC223/ERC223Burnable.sol";
import "./ERC223-token-standard-development/token/ERC223/ERC223Mintable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC223Burnable, ERC223Mintable{
}
```

The first strange Thing is that I get this warning when compiling:

```
Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to view
    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyMinter returns (bool) {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

I think this is weird because to my understanding it changes the state of the contract and should not be a view function

However after creating my contract and using the `mint` function the totalSupply is still 0 even though `isMinter(myaddr)` returns `true`. I thought that I was just doing something wrong in the truffle testfile but after I pushed my code into Remix I still get the same warning and the total supply is still 0.

I hope you can help me with this issue.

Comment: Alternatively you could look at creating ERC777 tokens. See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC777

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

*Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your question, it looks like a bug in your [_mint](https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard/blob/development/token/ERC223/ERC223Mintable.sol#L55) function:

```
function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyMinter returns (bool) {
    _totalSupply.add(amount);
    balances[msg.sender].add(amount);
    return true;
}
```

Let's see how `add` method of [SafeMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol#L26) lib works:

```
function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

    return c;
}
```

First of all, its [pure](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#pure-functions) function, which doesn't modify the state of contract. It just returns amount of addition. So, it's expected behavior for your code ‘cause you don't save a result

But if you take a look at [open-zeppelin's](https://openzeppelin.com) [implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L172) of `_mint` method, they change contract's state

```
function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");

    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
    _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
}
```

I believe it's better to use OpenZeppelin's contracts for your development 'cause they have a lot of auditors

P.S. Also you don't use `address account` variable in `_mint()` and always add `amount` to `msg.sender` (yourself) in your implementation